# vercongent sequences

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

> **Definition-** We say a sequence $(x_n)$ *verconges to $x$* if there exist an $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $N\in \Bbb{N}$, $n\ge N \implies |x_n-x|<\epsilon$.

Loosely speaking, by convergent sequence we mean that a sequence is convergent to some point $x$ if we can confine its infinite "tail" in some neighbourhood of $x$.

In similar wordings, *vercongent* sequence should mean, that a sequence $(x_n)$ is *vercongent* to $x$ if  we are given a point in its infinite "tail", say $\mathfrak{n}\in \Bbb{N}$, then we can put a wall around $x$, in which whole tail after $\frak{n}$ must lie.

**Question-** Give an example of *convergent sequence* and one that is *not vercongent* or *verdigent*

According to me $(x_n)=\{1,\frac12,\frac13, \frac14, \dots \}$ *verconges* to $0$, also to $1$  as for any given $n\in \Bbb{N}$, all terms after $n$ lies in $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n}$ neighbourhood of $0$, clearly, and for $1$ we  $\epsilon=\frac{n-1}{n}$ works. I guess  a *convergent* sequence is also *vercongent*, with the same limit, any many more limits, almost any number works as a limit, am I correct?

But sequence $\{1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,\dots\}$ is not convergent as it is oscillatory but it is *vercongent* as for any natural number $\frak{n}$, we can always choose $\epsilon=10$ around $0$ or $1$ or $-1$, so it verconges to many numbers, a big enough epsilon will work. Thus *vercongent* does not imply *convergent*.

But on the other hand, sequence $\{1,2,3,\dots \}$ neither *converges* nor *verconges*.

Please correct me if I am wrong in this understanding of this exercise from Abbott's book "*Understanding Analysis*."

Comment: Every compact sequence is vercongent to any point (Beine-Horel theorem)

Comment: @A.G.: isn't that Spooner's corollary?

Comment: I think that this funny property is made up just for students to feel the difference between what they have hard time with at the beginning, namely, $\forall\epsilon$ and $\exists\epsilon$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **Claim:** Any real-valued sequence is “vercongent” if and only if it is bounded, in which case it “verconges” to every real number.

*Proof of sufficiency:* If $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded, then there exists some $M>0$ such that $|x_n|<M$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Hence, the sequence “verconges” to $0$. In fact, it “verconges” to *any* number $x\in\mathbb R$, as $|x_n-x|\leq|x_n|+|x|<M+|x|$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$.

*Proof of necessity:* Suppose that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ “verconges” to $x\in\mathbb R$ and let $\varepsilon >0$ be the constant of “vercongence.” Then, letting $N=1$ in the definition of “vercongence,” one has that for any $n\in\mathbb N$, $$|x_n|\leq |x_n-x|+|x|<\varepsilon+|x|.$$

---

**Added (generalization to metric spaces):** Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space.

> **Definition:** A sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $X$ is *vercongent* to $x\in X$ if there exists some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $d(x_n,x)<\varepsilon$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

$$\phantom{}$$

> **Claim:** Any sequence in $X$ is vercongent if and only if it is bounded, in which case it verconges to every $x\in X$.

*Proof of sufficiency:* If $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded, then the set $\{x_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb N\}$ can be included in a sufficiently large open ball. That is, there exists some $M>0$ and $y\in X$ such that $d(x_n,y)<M$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. In fact, the sequence is vercongent to any $x\in X$, since $$d(x_n,x)\leq d(x_n,y)+d(y,x)<M+d(x,y)\quad\text{for every $n\in\mathbb N$}.$$

*Proof of necessity:* Suppose that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ verconges to $x\in X$ and let $\varepsilon >0$ be the constant of vercongence. Then, it is easy to check that $$\{x_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb N\}\subseteq B(\varepsilon, x).$$

---

An alternative, and perhaps more widely used, definition of boundedness of a subset $A\subseteq X$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ is that its *diameter* $$\operatorname{diam}(A)\equiv\sup_{x,y\in A}d(x,y)\tag{$\clubsuit$}$$ is finite. To see that this is equivalent to the definition used above, suppose first that there is some $z\in X$ and $M>0$ such that $A\subseteq B(M,z)$. Then, for any $x,y\in A$, one has $$d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)<2M,$$ so that $\operatorname{diam}(A)\leq2M<\infty$. Conversely, if the supremum in ($\clubsuit$) is finite, then pick any $x\in A$ (if $A$ is empty, it is trivially included in any open ball). Then, for any $y\in A$, $$d(y,x)\leq\operatorname{diam}(A)<\operatorname{diam}(A)+1,$$ so that $$A\subseteq B(\operatorname{diam}(A)+1,x).$$

Comment: so we can say "vercongent" is synonym for "bounded". Is it true in any metric space?

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth Yes. I added a proof for metric spaces.

Comment: I will accept it after 24 hours. Thanks alot

Comment: "if $A$ is empty, it is trivially included in any open ball", but there aren't necessarily any open balls. $\hspace{.6 in}$ ($\hspace{.03 in}X$ could also be empty.) $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer I use the tacit assumption that a metric space must not be empty. You may not agree. In this case, we may perhaps agree on the convention that if $A$ is empty, then we call it “bounded” according to both definitions (all the more so because a supremum over the empty set likewise brings up problematic definitional issues, which are more annoying than illuminating).

Comment: @RickyDemer Any sequence in an empty space is vercongent, convergent, and married to a unicorn

Answer (score 5):

You're correct that *vercongent* is more general than *convergent*, but note that *vercongent* does not actually have to do with the tail of $(x_n)$. In fact, since for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $n\geq N\implies |x_n-x|<\epsilon$, we can take $N=1$ in particular to see that $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Thus, a vercongent sequence is bounded; can you prove that every bounded sequence is vercongent (to **any** point in $\mathbb{R}$)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. This horrible distortion of English (and Latin) is a synonym for bounded: a sequence $x_n$ is "vercongent" (to anything you like) iff for some $b$, $|x_n| < b$ for all $n$.